# Развернуть Iframe на весь экран

Tags: javascript, iframe

Есть iframe, как сделать чтобы после нажатия на кнопку которая находится в iframe, iframe увеличивался на весь экран (fullscreen)?
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно получить родителя:

```
 window.parent
```

Родителю, для простоты понимания, напишем функцию:

```
resizeIframe() {
    var iframe = document.getElementById('iframe');
    iframe.style.cssText += 'position: fixed; left: 0; top: 0;';
    iframe.style.width = document.body.clientWidth + 'px';
    iframe.style.height = document.body.clientHeight + 'px';
}
```

И кнопка во фрейме:

```
<button onclick="window.parent.resizeIframe();">Кнопка</button>
```

И самое главное, чтобы домен iframe'a совпадал с доменом родителя.

Comment: Спасибо! А есть возможность fullsceen использовать на других доменах. Любые идеи?

Comment: @DOsS политика безопасности говорит о том, что родитель и iframe могут взаимодействовать только на одном домене. Либо из родителя изменяйте положение окна iframe, либо никак.

Comment: iframe.style.cssText += 'position: fixed; left: 0; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0';

будет вполне достаточно)

Answer (score 1):

Можно просто заменить URL топа, кнопка в Ифреймe:

```
<input id="xbtExpand" type="button" value="Развернуть" onclick="top.location.href = location.href" />
```

работаеть на разных доменах.

Если такой подход неприемлим и если обе страницы находятся в одном домене - весь код из первого ответа можно расположить в самой Iframe, не трогая родителя, ифрейм может сам к себе обратиться как `frameElement`

Comment: Уау здорово! А можно это обратно завернуть? <input id="xbtExpand" type="button" value="Развернуть" onclick="top.location.href = location.href" />

Comment: В принципе да, самый простой способ - вернуться на предыдущий адрес:     `<input id="xbtCollapse" type="button" value="Свернуть" onclick="history.back()" />`

Answer (score 0):

нужен аттрибут allowfullscreen 
подробнее про [fullscreen в javascript](http://html5.by/blog/fullscreen-javascript-api)